# MySQL LEFT JOIN working but slow, INNER works when the db is populated

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a statistics page for users of my site to see how much they have been interacting with the various features. On the site they can do four different types of activity, get points for them, and give feedback to other users on their answers. These are all recorded in the database.

- In the points tables, a row is created when a user does something for the first time, for example watches a particular video. There is a new row for each video.
- In the feedback tables, a row is created for each unique piece of feedback, with user id, feedback etc.

The problem I am having is that whlst two types of join work to get the expected output, INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN they have have radically different execution times.

- LEFT JOIN executes but takes forever (and subsequently crashes my low memory computer!).
- INNER JOIN executes but only if all the tables have at least one matching row for the user.

Im sure therefore I am missing some efficiency step here, or misunderstanding the usage of the joins in this context. I could use help looking at the SQL statement and looking at how it could be improved.

Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dce51 (with limited data due to size!)

The problems are with the groups of eight below - the other queries execute swiftly and properly.

```
SELECT      users.forename, users.surname, users.email, 
users_peer_request.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT users_peer_request.id) as peer_req_cnt, 
COUNT(DISTINCT users_self_assessment.id) AS self_assess_cnt, AVG(users_self_assessment.assessment) AS self_assess_avg, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT classes.name, '-', classes.id SEPARATOR ',') AS classes,

COUNT(DISTINCT a_experiment_points.id) AS tried_exp, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a_phetlabs_points.id) AS tried_phet, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a_videonotes_points.id) AS tried_video, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a_working_points.id) AS tried_work,                            
COUNT(DISTINCT a_experiment_feedback.id) AS fb_exp, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a_phetlab_feedback.id) AS fb_phet, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a_videonotes_feedback.id) AS fb_video, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a_working_feedback.id) AS fb_work

FROM        users_peer_request
LEFT JOIN   classes ON classes.id IN (SELECT classes_students.class_id FROM classes_students WHERE classes_students.student_id = users_peer_request.user_id) 
LEFT JOIN   users ON users.gid = users_peer_request.user_id
LEFT JOIN   users_self_assessment ON users_self_assessment.user_id = users_peer_request.user_id

INNER JOIN   a_experiment_points  ON   a_experiment_points.user_id =  users_peer_request.user_id
INNER JOIN   a_phetlabs_points    ON   a_phetlabs_points.user_id =  users_peer_request.user_id
INNER JOIN   a_videonotes_points  ON   a_videonotes_points.user_id =  users_peer_request.user_id
INNER JOIN   a_working_points     ON   a_working_points.user_id =  users_peer_request.user_id 
INNER JOIN   a_experiment_feedback  ON   a_experiment_feedback.user_fb_id =  users_peer_request.user_id
INNER JOIN   a_phetlab_feedback    ON   a_phetlab_feedback.user_fb_id =  users_peer_request.user_id
INNER JOIN   a_videonotes_feedback  ON   a_videonotes_feedback.user_id_fb =  users_peer_request.user_id
INNER JOIN   a_working_feedback     ON   a_working_feedback.user_fb_id =  users_peer_request.user_id

WHERE       users_peer_request.user_id = 123456789123456789123456
GROUP BY    users_peer_request.user_id
```

This query run on the fiddle provided I would hope returns NULL or 0 where the user does not appear in the table, and a number otherwise which counts that value.

Thanks so much, I hope you have enough detail here but if not please ask :)

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Why do you use sub-query to select classes? `LEFT JOIN   classes ON classes.id IN (SELECT classes_students.class_id FROM classes_students WHERE classes_students.student_id = users_peer_request.user_id) 
` As I understood, the query returns list of all class_id for *all* users, not only for requested. Maybe it is better to join tables without sub-query?

Comment: Jarlh: It is grouped by a SELECTed statement, users_peer_request.user_id is in that first statement.    Ivan: Perhaps that could be better - would you think its a cause of the speed problem though? That statement worked fine and fast before I introduced those groups of 8.

Comment: @AlexanderBunting . . . So much use of `COUNT(DISTINCT)` suggests a problem with the query.  I suspect that you need to aggregate along each dimension *before* joining rather than joining everything together and getting a big Cartesian product for each user.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how one might aggregate along a dimension? Im a bit stuck on what you are suggesting with reference to my problem...